# hadoop hive question

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to create tables pragmatically using JDBC. However, I can't really see the table I created from the hive shell. What's worse, when i access hive shell from different directories, i see different result of the database.
Is any setting i need to configure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you run hive from the same directory every time because when you launch hive CLI for the first time, it creates a metastore derby db in the current directory. This derby DB contains metadata of hive tables. If you change directories, you will have unorganized metadata for hive tables. Also the **Derby DB cannot handle multiple sessions**. To allow for concurrent Hive access you would need to use a real database to manage the Metastore rather than the wimpy little derbyDB that comes with it. You can download mysql for this and change hive properties for jdbc connection to mysql type 4 pure java driver.

Answer (score 1):

Try emailing the Hive userlist or the IRC channel.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to setup the central Hive metastore (by default, Derby, but it can be mySQL/Oracle/Postgres). The metastore is the "glue" between Hive and HDFS. It tells Hive where your data files live in HDFS, what type of data they contain, what tables they belong to, etc.

For more information, see http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HiveDerbyServerMode

Answer (score 0):

Examine your hadoop logs. For me this happened when my hadoop system was not setup properly. The namenode was not able to contact the datanodes on other machines etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's due to the metastore not being set up properly. Metastore stores the metadata associated with your Hive table (e.g. the table name, table location, column names, column types, bucketing/sorting information, partitioning information, SerDe information, etc.).

The default metastore is an embedded Derby database which can only be used by one client at any given time. This is obviously not good enough for most practical purposes. You, like most users, should configure your Hive installation to use a different metastore. MySQL seems to be a popular choice. I have used [this link](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Hive+Installation#HiveInstallation-ConfiguringtheHiveMetastore) from Cloudera's website to successfully configure my MySQL metastore.